# 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' at the end of Invoke

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, user-interface, delegates, invoke

I have just learnt how to set up a GUI in a separate thread...

```
Private myGui As SomeGui
Public Class myAsyncState
    Public a As Boolean = True
    Public b As Integer = 100
End Class

Public Sub Caller()
    '
    myGui = New SomeGui()
    ' setup
    myGui.Begin()
    Dim a as Boolean = False
    Dim b as Integer = 1
    Dim state As myAsyncState = New myAsyncState(a, b)
    Dim step1 As New xDelegate(AddressOf xMethod)
    Dim callBack As New AsyncCallback(AddressOf xMethod_Callback)            
    Dim asyncResultTest As IAsyncResult = step1.BeginInvoke(a, b, callBack, state)

End Sub

Private Delegate Sub xDelegate(Byval a as Integer, ByVal b As Boolean) 
Public Sub xMethod(Byval a as Integer, ByVal b As Boolean)     
End Sub

Private Sub xMethod_Callback(ByVal ia As IAsyncResult)
    Dim myAsyncResult As AsyncResult = CType(ia, AsyncResult)
    Dim myAsyncMethodCaller As xDelegate = CType(myAsyncResult.AsyncDelegate, xDelegate)
    Dim state As myAsyncState = CType(myAsyncResult.AsyncState, myAsyncState)
    myAsyncMethodCaller.EndInvoke(ia)
    xMethod_Finish(state.a, state.b)
End Sub

Private Sub xMethod_Finish(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Boolean)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
      Invoke(New xDelegate(AddressOf xMethod_Finish), New Object() {a, b})   ' here

' Also tried Invoke(New xDelegate(AddressOf xMethod_Finish), a, b)   though the above is what I have seen in documentation
' also tried to make Dim state As myAsyncState = New myAsyncState(a, b) and use it as an argument
        Else
            yMethod(a, b)
            myGui.Finish()
        End If
    End Sub
```

I was returning and passing values, it was all so good... and then I returned to it to test it, and got an error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
```

The exception was after "xMethod" completed, on the line I show "here" - in the xMethod_Finish. It looks like there are some mismatched parameters - but I thought I had them all correct - and I put a lot of effort in understanding how to pass parameters to the delegate, so that they can also be passed to the subsequent method, after the EndInvoke of the first one (that will still be in the GUI thread).

Please help me see what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your invokation looks correct.

The error is likely in the `yMethod` or `myGui.Finish()` methods.  Exceptions can become a little hidden when they occur in an invoked method.  Check the exception's `InnerException` property to gain more information and the stack trace of what's causing the `KeyNotFoundException`.

You can set a breakpoint in the problem methods to debug the error.

Comment: Thanks, I have figured that out. The fact that the error was on the Invoke, and my lack of experience, made me spend a few hours trying to debug the wrong problem...